# Problem with Quiz that doesn't print result when onClick

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I have been trying to create a Quiz, but my code doesn't print result and I don't know which could be a problem.

```
function onlyCheck() {
var resposta = document.getElementByName("res").value;

if (resposta == perguntas.respostaCorreta[0]) {
    document.getElementById("acerto").innerHTML = "Acertou";
} else {
     document.getElementById("acerto").innerHTML = "Errou";
}
```

https://codepen.io/braian-christian/pen/GRRKdVg

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/KKKPezX

What I changed was:

1. I took the `value="x"` out of the buttons and used `onclick="onlyCheck(x)"` (where `x` is 0-3) instead.
2. Changed your `onlyCheck` function like this:

```
function onlyCheck(resposta) {
    if (resposta == perguntas.respostaCorreta) {
...
```

This was the biggest problem, since `document.getElementByName("res").value` was always going to match the first button, no matter what, since all of the buttons have the same name, and because `perguntas.respostaCorreta` was defined, but not `perguntas.respostaCorreta[0]`.

3. Took out the `<form>`...`</form>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

For one, `getElementByName` is plural, `getElementsByName`, and returns a NodeList, basically an array of elements.  Also, I don't see where you're trying to print anything.  What are you trying to accomplish when the button is clicked?